# The angle bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C_{ex}$ intersect at point $E$. If $\angle A=70^o$, what is $\angle E$ equal to?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

The angle bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C_{ex}$ intersect at point $E$. If $\angle A=70^\circ$, what is $\angle E$ equal to?

[image]

I tried to solve this question as follows:

$a=\angle EBC$ and $b=\angle BCA$

$2a+b=110^{\circ}$

Also $\angle ACE= 90^\circ-\frac{b}{2}$

This is as far as I got. I don't know how to work out what $\angle E$ is equal to. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: Hint: let $\angle ACE=x$ then show that $\angle EBC=x-25$ then use triangle property in $\Delta EBC$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore understood implicitly, I didn't think of that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate incenter $I$ (on $BE$) and connect $I$ with $C$. It is known $\angle BIC = 90+A/2$.

Also $\angle BIC$ is the exterior angle to $\triangle ICE$ where $\angle ICE=90^{\circ}$. (Why?) Clearly by exterior-angle property applied to $\triangle ICE$, $\angle E=A/2$.

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, $\angle ACE = \frac{\angle A + \angle B}{2}$

So, $\angle BCE = \frac{\angle A + \angle B}{2} + \angle C$

$\angle CBE = \frac{\angle B}{2}$

So $\angle E = 180^0 - (\frac{\angle B}{2} + \frac{\angle A + \angle B}{2} + \angle C) = ?$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the measure of the angle $\angle ABC$= $2x$ and the $\angle C_{ex}$ = $2y$ .
By the exterior angle theorem, we have

$70^{\circ}$+$2x$ = $2y$

$y$ - $x$ = $35^{\circ}$

$\angle ACB$ = $180^{\circ}$-$2y$  (because both the angles add upto $180^{\circ}$)

Since $EB$ and $EC$ are the angle biectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ respectively, $\angle EBC$ = $x$ and $\angle ACE$ = y.

Considering the triangle $BEC$,

$\angle E$ + $\angle EBC$ + $\angle BCE$ = $180^{\circ}$

$\angle E$ + $x$ +  $180^{\circ}$-$2y$ + $y$ = $180^{\circ}$  ( since $\angle ACB$ + $\angle ACE$ = $\angle BCE$)

$\angle E$ = $y$ - $x$ = $35^{\circ}$